# Shifting command output to the right

Tags: bash, text-processing, indentation

Say I'm writing a `.bashrc` file to give me some useful information in my login terminals and I'm telling it to run the cal command (a nice one).  How would I go about shifting the calendar produced to the right to match the formatting of the rest of my `.bashrc` "welcome message"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
cal | sed 's/^/     /'
```

#### Explanation

- `cal |`: pipe the output of cal to…
- `sed 's/^/     /'` sed, which will look for the start of lines `^`, replacing with spaces. You can change the number of spaces here to match the required formatting.

---

### Edit

To preserve the highlighting of the current day from `cal`, you need to tell it to output "color" (highlighting) to the pipe. From `man cal`

```
   --color [when]
          Colorize output.  The when can be never, auto, or always.  Never will turn off coloriz‐
          ing  in  all  situations.  Auto is default, and it will make colorizing to be in use if
          output is done to terminal.  Always will allow colors to be outputed when  cal  outputs
          to pipe, or is called from a script.
```

N.B. there seems to be a typo in the manual; I needed a `=` for it to work. Hence, the final command is

```
cal --color=always | sed 's/^/     /'
```

Comment: I just realized that for a command like `cal` the highlighted day is lost.  Is there a way to keep it?

Comment: @theStandard Good point! I've edited in the information.

Comment: `--color=always` doesn't work for me

Comment: @theStandard I guess try `--color always`? What does `man cal` say for you?

Comment: @theStandard This is for `cal from util-linux 2.24.2` (obtainable with `$ cal --version`).

Comment: This works great but when the command I'm running is `scp` it fails to output anything. My guess is it's down to the way `scp` outputs things. Any ideas?

Comment: @AdrianLynch Are you talking about secure copying (`scp`) a file over the network? I wouldn't expect `~/.bashrc` to execute during `scp`.

Comment: @Sparhawk - I'm running something like `scp server:/path/*.log ./ | sed 's/^/     /'` but it fails to pass the output through sed.

Comment: This question is about piping and reformatting the output of `cal`. Your first command `scp server:/path/*.log ./` wouldn't show any (unformatted) `cal` output, right? So there's nothing to pipe into the `sed` command.

Answer (score 8):

```
cal | nl -bn
```

...will work because `nl` always indents input lines it doesn't number to equal the indent it would add to those it does. By default `nl` does not number `-h`eader or `-f`ooter sections of input, and only numbers `-b`ody lines. If you also tell it `n`ot to number `-b`ody lines it will number nothing at all and only insert indentation to every input line.

Use the `-w`idth and `-s`eparator switches to adjust the size of the indent.

---

```
cal; cal | nl -bn
```

---

```
    December 2015   
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
       1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30 31       

           December 2015   
       Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
              1  2  3  4  5 
        6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
       13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
       20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
       27 28 29 30 31
```

---

There is also:

```
cal | pr -to[num]
```

...where *`[num]`* is the number of spaces you want inserted at the head of each line. `pr` usually prints 66 lines per *page*, but the `-t` tells it to omit its header/footer inserts and just print input to output. The `-o`ffset margin switch is then used to insert as many spaces as are requested in *`[num]`* at the head of each output line:

```
cal; cal | pr -to10
```

---

```
    December 2015   
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
       1  2  3  4  5 
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
27 28 29 30 31       

              December 2015   
          Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                 1  2  3  4  5 
           6  7  8  9 10 11 12 
          13 14 15 16 17 18 19 
          20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
          27 28 29 30 31
```

Answer (score 6):

With `paste`:

```
cal | paste /dev/null -
```

`paste` pastes the lines of files together with TAB characters in  between. Here we paste the empty file (`/dev/null`) with `paste`'s stdin (`-`) which is the output of `cal` fed via a pipe.

Comment: great! but could you explain please how it works?

Comment: @august0490, see edit.

Comment: Now I understand the dash `-` is a `paste` parameter to indicate to take the stdin. I though it was the delimiter hehe. Maybe another example more didactic would be `cal | paste /dev/null -d"\t" -` where you can see the delimiter more clearly. Thanks.

Comment: @august0490, in POSIX compliant `paste` implementations, that would paste the `/dev/null`, `-d\t` files and stdin. Options need to go before non-option arguments. Bear in mind that `-d string` doesn't insert `string` in between columns but `s` between the first and second, `t` between the 2nd and 3rd, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `sed`:

```
cal | sed -e 's/^/    /'
```

The above will indent the calendar by four spaces by inserting them at the start (`^`) of every line. You can change the indentation as you wish, or add other pieces of output.

If you want it perfectly right-aligned in any terminal you can use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf) and [`stty`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stty) with a more ugly loop:

```
read height width < <(stty size)
cal | while read line ; do printf "%${width}s" "$line" ; done
```

(`stty size` is non-standard but widely supported)

Comment: Jinx! +1 though. :)

Comment: Is there a way to put the output of two commands next to each other?

Comment: You can use `curses` (or terminal escapes) to set things up that way, but it's a pretty fraught process. Other than that, one neat trick: if the command output is substantially different, you can trick `diff` into making a side-by-side diff of both: `diff -y -W 80 <(some command) <(cal)`.

Comment: @theStandard: `paste <(cal) <(cal) <(cal)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is example using `ex`:

```
ex +"%norm 20I " +%p -scq! <(cal)
```

Change `20` into number of required spaces. Using `"%norm 20I "` is more efficient than repeating many spaces with substitution - `"%s/^/   /"`.

Comment: `ex` can read stdin. and it will quit at eof automatically if it does - why `<(`thing`)`?

Comment: @mikeserv Seems it doesn't quit on eof: `cal | ex +"%norm 20I " +%p /dev/stdin` (you've to manually type `q!`). `<()` instead of pipe, otherwise you need to write `/dev/stdin`, so it's longer and doesn't look clean: `cal | ex +"%norm 20I " +%p -scq! /dev/stdin`.

Comment: you have to use `-`.

Comment: @mikeserv `-` it seems it doesn't work: `cal | ex +"%norm 20I " +%p -scq! -`