# Indent output even for partial lines

Tags: bash, sed, scripting, terminal, text-formatting

I'm trying to indent the output of 'subcommands' in a script, like this:

```
Turning off image...
    Unmounting...done.
    Detaching loop device...done
```

where the indented items are individual steps executed during `Turning off image...`.

The standard solution is to use `sed` et. al. like in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148109/) however some of the steps in my script require prompting the user to confirm an action using `read`. Since the prompt is not terminated in a newline, it is not output by `sed` until after the `read` command completes. Is there a way around this?

**Clarification:** One of the subcommands itself is calling `read` with a prompt. When the subcommand is piped through `sed`, `sed` won't output the prompt because it is not yet terminated with a newline.

Here's example code (somewhat contrived to get the point across):

```
function indent () { (set -o pipefail;  "$@" 2>&1 | sed 's/^/    /';); }

function some_cleanup () {
    # ... some commands
    read -rp "Do you want to force a dismount? (y/n)" yesno
    if [ "$yesno" = "yes" ]; then force_dismount; fi
}

indent some_cleanup
```

Comment: What prompt? Sed doesn't ever prompt as far as I know. What sed command? What `read` command? We can't help you debug a command if you don't show it to us. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: @terdon I've added clarification/code

Comment: @Kusalananda: I prefer having a wrapper function that I can use generically to indent when I wish to. Some times the command may be executed when I don't want to indent it. It's best to avoid sprinkling every single command with its own indentation.

Comment: Prompts are usually output on stderr, which is why sed doesn't process them.

Comment: @glennjackman Even if I `printf` the prompt without the newline it doesn't help. As to be expected, I believe.